Why does the ACF Field not work in WordPress Divi Engine?
I am facing the issue that I cannot understand why I cannot use an "Advanced Custom Field Value" - ACF - within a divi social media module. I have to use a "ACF Item - Divi Machine" Module. Why does the linking works on one but not the other?
On the social media module, I click on the database icon (picture) and select the ACF Type:


And this is what I have to use now:

I would be very thankful for a solution. BR
Using Divi Social Media Icons with ACF

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
